# I want a transforming jquery button up/down id tag button in the right down corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My dear friends,

I am not that kind of hacker and not familar wit jquery or javascript.
But I know, there must be a way to get a code snippet that does exactly
what google programmed. If I klick on the button in the right down corner the view jumps down every ID until it reaches the bottom.
Than the arrow transforms to an "up" arrow and a klick brings me back up like on this site.

https://www.google.com/intl/de/gmail/about/

I searched for a lots of solutions but truthfully I don't know where to start.

On my page the scroll down view scrolls slow to an id, but a button is a complete other dimension of skills. (ingomichalski.com)
But there MUST be a way to create a script that creates a button that scroll down to different ids. Is someone out there that has the skill to do this?
I googled since houres but i only found some grey ugly button scripts..

Please help!

Regards, Ingo

Comment: All that time you spent trying to find someone else's code for a button, you could have just learned how to do it and made it yourself

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element) is what you're looking for. You'd have to make an array of elements, every time the user clicks the button you increase a number and scroll to a different element.

Comment: @RSon1234 Is there a free course out there to learn this quick? All courses I found starts at "hello world" and defining variables.. Maby you can help. I will do the work but I am overwhelmed how and where to start?

Comment: Thank you both - that could help! It is more easy how to search with nowing the language - big thanks @Jespertheend

Comment: I always recommend https://www.codecademy.com/ you'll learn the basics of javascript in about 5 hours. If you've never coded before I always recommend starting with python. But since javascript is what you need right now, that's probably the one you'll want to go with.

Comment: **OMG** @Jespertheend That course is **incredible**!! I searched so long for a course like that!! Thanks thanks thanks!! Now I understand all the "p"s and <ul>s and <ol>s, incredible! _(You see, I can format now!! ;-) )_